# MySQL: SHOW PROFILES - Want to see more than 100 records

Tags: mysql, performance

I am performance profiling my queries and need to be able to see a lot more than the last 100 queries. Max profiling_history_size is 100, but I've seen debug tools that somehow manage to save more than the last 100 queries (for example, django debug tool).

I do

```
SET profiling=1;
set profiling_history_size = 100;
SHOW PROFILES;
```

It would be fine if I could move the records to another table. Or maybe I need to be looking somewhere else altogether?

My program runs the same queries a lot of times, so what I really want is an aggregate of all the times that a particular query was executed. I was going to do some kind of GROUP BY once I had all the queries, but maybe there is some other place to look? (I don't mean to ask 2 questions, but maybe knowing what I eventually need will change the answer to the above question.)

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL 5.6, the statements (queries) are instrumented by the performance schema.

You get the time a query takes, plus many more attributes such as the number of rows returned, etc, and you get many different aggregations.

See

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/statement-summary-tables.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema-statements-tables.html

An aggregation that is particularly useful is the aggregation by digest, to group several "similar queries" together, where similar means the same structure but possibly different literal values ("select * from t1 where id = 1" and "select * from t1 where id = 2" will be aggregated together as "select * from t1 where id = ?")

Answer (score 0):

If you need information for more than the last 100 queries, you will simply need to collect existing data every 100 queries. I have implemented the latter feature in PHP PDO.

https://github.com/gajus/doll

This is an application layer solution.